# GSUITE: Migrating email from old domain after having moved domain name

Tags: email, dns, migration, google-workspace

The current mailprovider has had technical issues for more than 14 days now until last night when their servers came offline.
They are insisting that the issue will be solved, but I've gone ahead and prepared to move to gsuite.
I started the mail migration tool several days ago but it fails after migrating a few mails due to the old providers tech issues.

**My question is:**
If I move the MX records to gsuite, I will receive emails again, but would it then be possible to migrate old mails at a later time? (In case the my old provider fixes their issues?)

My concern is, that when I move the domain name, I will no longer have access to my old emails on the old server.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the MX records so, that new mails will appear in gsuite.
This means, that the old mails won't migrate, since the MX records has changed.

When the old host, hopehully works again, I'll switch the records temporarily, move the mails and change the MX back to gsuite again.